# 'Acces denied' error with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++

I get some errors when I build my code in Visual Studio 10, and I don't know how I can solve it. This is a error message that I got:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Win32Project34, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppClean.targets(76,5): warning : Access to the path 'c:\users\recht\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\win32project34\debug\win32project34.exe' is denied.
1>einde5.cpp
1>c:\users\recht\desktop\einde5.cpp(37): warning C4302: 'type cast': truncation from 'LPWSTR' to 'WORD'
1>c:\users\recht\desktop\einde5.cpp(42): warning C4302: 'type cast': truncation from 'LPWSTR' to 'WORD'
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'c:\users\recht\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Win32Project34\Debug\Win32Project34.exe'
1>Done building project "Win32Project34.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Does someone know what the problem is, and how I can solve it?

Comment: running copy of Win32Project34.exe?

Comment: what version of Windows do you have ?

Comment: If this is solved, please add or accept a solution below. We do not use [solved] title hacks here.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your application

```
c:\users\recht\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\win32project34\debug\win32project34.exe
```

is still running.

Use taskmanager to terminate it or call

```
taskkill /f /IM win32project34.exe
```

in a cmd window to make sure it is gone before you try to relink.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Visual Studios as an administrator (Right click, run as administrator on program link).